# Bitmap and proper saving location

Tags: java, android

Hi everybody I've got the following problem with an adroid app: I want to read an image saved and perform some operations on it. 
(I do not need to use this image to draw something on screen, I just have to check the color of some pixels)

I'm using the following code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("drawable-v24/ean13.bmp");
```

The fact is that the BitmapFactory returns null as a FileNotFoundException is thrown. (by now the file is saved inside res folder)

I don't really understand where I should put the image and how to give the path to the BitmapFactory to be able to get it properly.

(I guess the problem is due to the fact that the image actually is stored on my pc and not on the Android device but I can't understand how should I proceed)

Thank you in advance for the help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are accessing image from resource `drawable` of  `mipmap`. You should use `BitmapFactory.decodeResource` to get `Bitmap`.

```
Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
```

Or another overloaded version .

> public static Bitmap decodeResource(Resources res, int id, Options opts)

where `getResources()` is method of `Activity`.

Comment: id is name of your image . if you put in `drawable` then id will be `R.drawable.imagename`.

Comment: Ok now it's clear thank you for your time it works :D